# Capybara não instala no Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Pessoal sou novo com Ruby e queria uma ajuda, estava tentando instalar o capybara com Ruby mas não estou conseguindo.

O erro é:

Gem::RuntimeRequirementNotMetError: capybara requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0. The
current ruby version is 2.3.3.222.
An error occurred while installing capybara (3.28.0), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara -v '3.28.0' --source
'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Brandon

Estava com os mesmos problemas que vc e agora montei um passo a passo:

1) Salvei todos os meus arquivos de testes(trabalho) e gem (configuração)

2) Desinstalei tudo

3) Baixe e instalei o seguinte release do ruby:

Fonte:

=> Para a Plataforma x64 usamos o link abaixo: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-2.4.5-1/rubyinstaller-2.4.5-1-x64.exe

=> Para a Plataforma x86 usamos o link abaixo: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-2.4.5-1/rubyinstaller-2.4.5-1-x86.exe

4) Instalei o rubyinstaller*.exe e ao final fiz as atualizações [1,2,3].

5) No comand.com do Ruby: ruby -v => identifico que o ruby instalado é o ruby 2.4.0

6) No comand.com do Ruby: gem install bundler (gerenciador de pacotes do ruby)

7) No comand.com do Ruby: gem install cucumber

8) No comand.com do Ruby: bundle init

9) No comand.com do Ruby: cucumber --init